# Change field of a TextBox with Button click at the same index in Data Binded List View

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `ListView` with a collection as `ItemsSource`.

```cs
<ListView x:Name="lvBT" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentPoste.TableauxBT}" Margin="0,0,0,12"
        IsEnabled="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentPoste.BtEdition, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:BT">
            [...]

            <TextBox x:Name="tbNumSerieBT"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,32,16,0" Text="{x:Bind NumSerie, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="16"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Button x:Name="bScannerBT"  Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,32,15,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Scanner tabeau BT" FontSize="14" Click="BScannerBT_Click"/>

            [...]
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

`tableauxBT` is representing a collection of `BT` objects and for each object in that collection I'm creating a DataTemplate, like basic data binding.

When I click on the `Button` in that template I'm scanning a barcode with a `BarcodeScanner` and want to put the return value in the `TextBox` field.

For each button of each different `BT` item I want to scan a different barcode but the problem is that I don't know how to get the index of the `Button` that was clicked to put the value in the right `TextBox`.

So how can I do to get the index of the clicked `Button` to put the value in the `TextBox` at the same index ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the index of the clicked button using the "BScannerBT_Click" method.

```
public BScannerBT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  var myClickedButton = (Button)sender; //this object hold all information you need.
  //You can reach the button's dataContext and change the value you want to.
  var buttonDataContext = myClickedButton.DataContext.
  //now you have the ViewModel (buttonDataContext) associated with the  'NumSerie'
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Ok, so I have the DataContext but what can I do in order to get the right TextBox ?

Comment: Edit : I got it ! I didn't understood that the DataContext was referring to the custom class object but now it's good